# Asynchronously add to queue, synchronously process it

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue, python-asyncio

I have a function `def event(...)` in my `EventHandler` class which can be called at arbitrary intervals in my main code. It needs to put all the events that are coming in into a queue and process them one at a time. How do I do this? I've been trying to use the asyncio library to do this, but I have no clue how to do it. My problem is that if I make `event` async, then I get the error that it was never awaited. If I don't make it async, then I can't call the function that processes the next item in the queue.

```
async def _event(...):
    queue_item = await(self._queue.get())
    ...
```

I need to be able to call event at any time, but the helper function `_event` needs to processes the next item in queue one at a time.

How do I solve this?

I tried making event synchronous

```
def event(...):
    """
    When an event happens, this will add it to the queue. Multiple events can happen, and they will be executed one at a time, as they come in. Later on, we can change this.
    """
    self._queue.put_nowait((flag, *args))
    task = self._loop.create_task(self._event())
    asyncio.ensure_future(task)
```

but then the error that comes up is that task was not awaited.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the problem but can't help wondering if it would be easier to just have your queue consumer running as a thread. Maybe asyncio offers little or no benefit in this case and just leads to unnecessary complexity

Comment: Could you give more details? Here's a few questions. Your `EventHandler` and `event` function are running in ne thread while you have an `asyncio` event loop running in another thread? Is that correct? And it appears your`EventHandler` class has a reference to the event loop? And lastly, you have an `asyncio.Queue` that is processing messages inside the event loop? You should specify which queue module you are using. Lastly, does `event` just put things on the queue or does it also need a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending more details from the poster, here is an example that has a `MainThreadClass` running on the main thread of a program and an `asyncio` event loop running on another thread. When `MainThreadClass.event` is called, it sends a message to the event loop via an `asyncio.Queue` and `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`. From there, the `asyncio` event loop is continuously listening for messages on the queue and processes the message, printing it to the console.

```py
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

class MainThreadClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create an `asyncio.Queue` so that the main thread can send messages
        # to the `asyncio` event loop via this queue and `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`
        self._async_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self._async_event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    
    def event(self, some_incoming_data):
        # You can't directly use `put_nowait` here because `asyncio.Queue` methods
        # not threadsafe
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self._async_queue.put(some_incoming_data), self._async_event_loop)

async def listen_to_queue(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        print(f"async event loop received: {message}")
        # ... do something with `message` ...
    
async def async_main(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    await asyncio.gather(listen_to_queue(queue))
        
def start_asyncio_event_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Starts the given `asyncio` loop on whatever the current thread is"""
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


def run_event_loop(queue: asyncio.Queue, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Runs the given `asyncio` loop on a separate thread, passing the `AsyncInbox`
    to the event loop for any other thread to send messages to the event loop.
    """
    thread = Thread(target=start_asyncio_event_loop, args=(loop,))
    thread.start()

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_main(queue), loop=loop)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_thread_class = MainThreadClass()
    async_queue = main_thread_class._async_queue
    async_event_loop = main_thread_class._async_event_loop

    run_event_loop(queue=async_queue, loop=async_event_loop)
    main_thread_class.event("testing")
```

This program prints the following to the console:

```
async event loop received: testing
```