Why does gevent affect the asyncio usage of child thread？

gevent version: 20.10.2
Python version: cPython 3.9
Operating System: macOS 14.3.1(M3)

Description:
I use gevent patch for my program, but in the program, I need to execute asyncio related code in sub threads
When multiple sub threads execute the same coroutine, it triggers "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running"
They are different threads, I generated its own event loop for each sub thread，I cannot understand this issue
When I commented out the monkey patch, the program executed as I expected
ERROR:root:This event loop is already running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/computer1/pytest/test.py", line 30, in func1
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncf1())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 583, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
/Users/computer1/pytest/test.py:32: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'asyncf1' was never awaited
  logging.error(e, exc_info=True)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
ERROR:root:This event loop is already running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/computer1/pytest/test.py", line 30, in func1
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncf1())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.18_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 583, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

What I've run:
import logging

import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import concurrent.futures

import threading
import time
import asyncio

pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

async def asyncf1():
    print("aa")
def func1():
    # print(f"thread:{threading.get_ident()},gevent:{id(gevent.getcurrent())}")
    try:
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        except RuntimeError:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            # asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncf1())
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e, exc_info=True)
    print(threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(3)


for i in range(3):
    pool.submit(func1)

time.sleep(10)



Is there a strong need to mix gevent and asyncio? As far as I know, they are two separate solutions to similar problems. It isn't very clear to me whether they can be mixed easily. But it appears that your problem isn't relevant to gevent.
From what I can see, your problem is that you actually aren't, at least always, launching the asyncio event loops on their own threads. You are submitting your func1 to a thread pool, not necessarily to individual, exclusive threads. I would imagine that you don't get this error every time because it depends on how the thread pool allocates your func1 in each of your for loop iterations to a thread. There's probably some race conditions too.
An asyncio event loop must be on its own thread and it effectively owns the entire thread for the duration of the event loop. Thus, you should explicitly create a thread for each event loop that you want to run.
See these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78256253/17800932
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78253105/17800932


Lastly, it is not clear what you need multiple event loops over just using one. Multiple event loops (and thus multiple threads) will be slower than a single event loop (and thus a single thread), and I can't see any actual benefit to multiple event loops.

You are correct, you should use either or.  You are going to run into problems especially after monkey patching where tasks are trying to be event driven in two simultaneous async paradigms.  This could cause all kinds of performance issues.
