How do you use asyncio module with TWS API in python?
I am trying to use async threads with TWS API in the asyncio module. It seems I have it working but I just need to possibly gather threads in a main function so they all run on the same event loop? Help is appreciated! The error and code are below. I also ran the subscribe function before starting the websocket thread and it works. It is just when I try to run it on a different thread.
class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)

    def position(self, account, contract, position, avgCost):
        
        global master_df

        global master_sub_req

        super().position(account, contract, position, avgCost)

        print("Position.", "Account:", account, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:",
              contract.secType, "Currency:", contract.currency,
              "Position:", decimalMaxString(position), "Avg cost:", floatMaxString(avgCost))

        row = {'Contract ID': contract.conId, 'Contract Symbol': contract.symbol, 'Position': position, 'Avg cost':avgCost}

        master_df = pd.concat((master_df, pd.DataFrame([row])))
        
        subscribe(contract.conId, contract)

    def positionEnd(self):

        print('position end')
    
    def pnlSingle(self, reqId, pos, dailyPnL, unrealizedPnL, realizedPnL, value):

        global master_df

        global master_sub_req

        super().pnlSingle(reqId, pos, dailyPnL, unrealizedPnL, realizedPnL, value)

        print("Daily PnL Single. ReqId:", reqId, "Position:", decimalMaxString(pos),
              "DailyPnL:", floatMaxString(dailyPnL), "UnrealizedPnL:", floatMaxString(unrealizedPnL),
              "RealizedPnL:", floatMaxString(realizedPnL), "Value:", floatMaxString(value))

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):    
        
        global master_df

        super().tickPrice(reqId, tickType, price, attrib)

        print(attrib)

        print("TickPrice. TickerId:", reqId, "tickType:", tickType, "Price:", price)

        for key, value in subscription_requests_tick_price:

            if master_df.loc[master_df['Contract Symbol'] == key]:

                master_df.loc[master_df['Contract Symbol'] == key,'Tick Price Request ID'] = value

                master_df.loc[master_df['Contract Symbol'] == key, "Market Price"] = price
'''
    def error(id, errorCode, errorMsg):

        print(errorCode)

        print(errorMsg)


async def subscribe(contract_id, contract):

    global master_sub_req

    master_sub_req += 1

    app.reqPnLSingle(master_sub_req, "DU7058034", "", contract_id)

    time.sleep(2)
    
    master_sub_req += 1

    app.reqMktData(reqId=master_sub_req, 
                contract=contract,
                genericTickList="",
                snapshot=False,
                regulatorySnapshot=False,
                mktDataOptions=[])

    time.sleep(2)
'''

def websocket_con():
    app.run()

app = TradingApp()

# starting a separate daemon thread to execute the websocket connection
con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con)

#define threading events to use for app threads
#position_event.set(), .clear(), .wait()

position_event = threading.Event()

pnl_single_event = threading.Event()

contract_details_event = threading.Event()

con_thread.start()

app.connect('127.0.0.1', 9225, clientId = 4)

app.reqPositions()

time.sleep(1)

async def subscribe(contract_id, contract):

    while True:

        global master_sub_req

        master_sub_req += 1

        app.reqPnLSingle(master_sub_req, "DU7058034", "", contract_id)

        time.sleep(2)
    
        master_sub_req += 1

        app.reqMktData(reqId=master_sub_req, 
                contract=contract,
                genericTickList="",
                snapshot=False,
                regulatorySnapshot=False,
                mktDataOptions=[])

        asyncio.sleep(2)

subscribe_thread = threading.Thread(target=subscribe, args =(app,))

subscribe_thread.start()

time.sleep(1)

Here is the error!

Exception in thread Thread-3 (subscribe):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: subscribe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'contract'
[Finished in 3.1s]


Your error has nothing to do with threads really or the asyncio event loop. The issue is what the error states:

TypeError: subscribe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'contract'

There are several issues with the line:
subscribe_thread = threading.Thread(target=subscribe, args =(app,))


You are not passing the correct arguments to subscribe. By your definition of subscribe, it takes two arguments: contract_id and contract. You are only passing it app.

subscribe is a coroutine. It cannot be directly called outside of an asyncio event loop. So even if you fix the argument error in the above line, you will get a new error when you try to start the thread because you can't run subscribe directly.



In general, it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish here with asyncio. To my knowledge, the TWS API doesn't have an asyncio implementation or module.
An asyncio event loop must run on its own thread and other code should not be ran there (in almost all cases) other than coroutines and tasks. If you want to start the event loop on its own thread, then you need to call something like asyncio.run as the target of a thread, passing it a main coroutine to run as an argument. See the answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78256253/17800932
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78253105/17800932

